# SuiteCRM Inline Edited Fields Not Saving

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, sugarcrm, suitecrm

In SuiteCRM, the default statuses and lead sources use names that have spaces in them which is illegal to create in the Studio. Instead we have custom status names such as "New_Lead" that don't match the label "New Lead". SuiteCRM tries to save the value as "New Lead" and fails, erasing any value to the field.

We have this in multiple places: Lead Status, Lead Source, Contact Source, Contact Status, etc. How can I fix the original problem as opposed to a hack fix I made that uses a logic hook to change the user entered value to an underscore instead of space?

Comment: What OS are you targeting ?  sugarorm tag is for Android ONLY.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to change inline editing js function which sending data to server. Apply URL function os javascript (if those are not). See complete JS of inline editing here: `include/InlineEditing/inlineEditing.js`

you need to check two function specifically : `handleSave` and `saveFieldHTML`